# Azure support for .NET 4.8

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone have any knowledge on Azure app service .NET 4.8 support. We
currently have a repository that we've started to move to .NET Core but because of our dependencies, we've had to target .NET 4.8. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Azure supports this framework version yet.

Does anyone have any ideas on timeline for if/when this might be supported? Or possible workarounds since we can't install third-party software on these services.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's anything in 4.8 that would be critical to an Azure App Service.  Can you target 4.7.x?

Comment: I just wanted to comment on this one:

.SameSite=(in our case)None

is a cookie property that only got implemented in 4.8.  And in a few weeks, it's gonna become REAL important (when Google flips the switch in chrome and changes the default behavior).

Comment: @FrogPr1nce 4.7.2 has the SameSite-property too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Update

[Jeff Martinez says](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/249):

> .NET Framework 4.8 support is coming to App Service.
>
> Public Azure cloud deployment will begin in mid-late July 2020
>   completing by mid-September 2020. For our Sovereign clouds, deployment
>   will begin by mid-late August 2020 and complete by early-October 2020.

---

As of late August 2019, updating Azure App Service to .Net 4.8 is `planned`.

Reference: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/37566262-upgrade-app-service-with-net-4-8

There have been no updates to Azure App Service since 19 August 2019.

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/updates/?product=app-service

Comment: Just to confirm: it *is* happening. See [App service announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/249) and [blog post](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/06/09/NET-Framework-4.8-is-coming-to-App-Service.html)

Comment: One question, Is it compulsory to update our APP as well if Azure updates the Framework of App service to 8?

Comment: Good question, Munavvar. I asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577840/is-it-required-to-update-web-apps-to-target-net-4-8-when-azure-app-services-upd

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but it has just been announced that deployment of .NET Framework 4.8 to Azure App Service will start in July 2020. See the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/249).

Hope this helps anyone looking for an update on this.

Answer (score 4):

According to my research, at the moment, Azure app service does not support .Net 4.8. Azure app service just supports up to .NET framework 4.7.2. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-App-Service/How-to-determine-the-installed-NET-version-in-Azure-App-Services/ba-p/392342). 
[image]

According to the situation, I suggest you make your application as a Container in Visual Studio then [deploy Container to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service/) or deploy your application to Azure VM.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.8 is supported now on Azure App service from 05 August, 2020
Check below update url for more info:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/app-service-net-framework-48-support-now-available/

You can also check it in Configuration settings of your existing App:
[image]